# Missed Chats on Skype using C#

Tags: c#, skype4com

Am trying to display unread chats from skype to my c# application.  I used     `int  msgCount=skype.MissedMessages.Count` to get number of unread messages and tried given functions `skype.MissedChats.ToString()` and    `skype.get_Message(msgCount).ToString()`. But they display " System._ComObject". Any suggestions???

Comment: What is the type of the `skype.MissedChats` property?

Comment: I got the answer.
..

It's posted here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is so simple and I got it as follows..

```
           for (int i = 0; i < skype.MissedMessages.Count; i++)
            {
                if (skype.MissedMessages[i + 1].Type == TChatMessageType.cmeSaid)
                {
                    string unreadMessage = skype.MissedMessages[i + 1].Body;
                }
             }
```

It's possible to read other details such as name of sender by     `skype.MissedMessages[i + 1].Sender`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that it would require you to use an indexer to actually display the content of one particular chat message. Right now you're converting a `ChatCollection` to a string, and I would guess that they haven't implemented that, so it just returns `this.GetType().Name`.

I would guess that the indexer would work like this:

```
List<string> messages = new List<string>();
foreach (Char c in skype.MissedChats)
{
    try
    {
        messages.Add(c.Name);
    }
    catch (COMException) { } // Invalid chat
}
```

Comment: I got the answer. .
It's posted here